# Windows Leaking Water

Tags: windows, leak

I have 2 hinged windows that are leaking water thru the frame when there's heavy rain and wind. And they leak the exact same way.

Would I be able to stop this by caulking or could it be a larger underlying problem? I have tried to diagnose where the leak is coming from but cannot determine how it's coming through.

Also, does anyone know what type of windows these are or who typically manufactures them?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what we're looking at here. Are those both interior shots? Generally speaking problems like this are addressed from the outside. Let's have a look at that.

Comment: Yes, they are both shots taken from the inside. It's hard to get an outside shot because the home is several floors up.

Comment: Aren't the windows on the ground floor the same model? (I've never heard of a window that opens both outward and inward.)

Comment: Sorry, I've edited to make more clear. Basically, you push the window out to open and pull it in to close.

Comment: First I would want to make sure the weep holes at the bottom of the track outside are clear so water that gets in them can drain. If they are not draining it would not take much to push water inside. When it is not raining they should drain rather quickly if you pour some water in the track. There are usually at least 2 and possibly more. Just a small slot only about a 1/16" wide by less than 1/2" long a tooth pick is a good tool to clear them but dust and dead flys plugg them.

Comment: This reminds me more of a skylight than a window....

Comment: They are awning windows. Where can I find weep holes for them?